# Named configuration error in centos 6.9

Tags: centos, bind

im getting this error when i try to run /etc/init.d/named restart in my vm what should i do to resolve this issue the error output is as follows:

```
[shan@server1 ~]$ sudo /etc/init.d/named restart
Stopping named:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting named: /etc/init.d/named: line 115:  2072 Aborted                 /usr/sbin/named-checkconf $ckcf_options ${named_conf} > /dev/null 2>&1

Error in named configuration:
/etc/named.conf:163: bad secret 'bad base64 encoding'
/etc/named.conf:163: bad secret 'bad base64 encoding'
/etc/named.conf:163: bad secret 'bad base64 encoding'
mem.c:1246: REQUIRE(ctx->references == 1) failed.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

my named.conf file is as follows:

```
Code: Select all
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { localhost; };
        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;

       /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};


logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};
zone shancked.com IN{
type master;
file "forward";
allow-update{none;};

};



include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

even after replacing the last key file i'm getting this problem.

```
[shan@server1 ~]$ sudo vi /etc/named.conf
[shan@server1 ~]$ sudo named-checkconf /etc/named.conf
[shan@server1 ~]$ sudo /etc/init.d/named restart
Stopping named:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting named: /etc/init.d/named: line 115:  2278 Aborted                 /usr/sbin/named-checkconf $ckcf_options ${named_conf} > /dev/null 2>&1

Error in named configuration:
/etc/named.conf:163: bad secret 'bad base64 encoding'
/etc/named.conf:163: bad secret 'bad base64 encoding'
/etc/named.conf:163: bad secret 'bad base64 encoding'
mem.c:1246: REQUIRE(ctx->references == 1) failed.
                                                           [FAILED]
[shan@server1 ~]$
```

After removing the bind-chroot i get the following error message:

```
[shan@server1 ~]$ sudo service named restart
Stopping named:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting named:
Error in named configuration:
forward:8: unknown RR type '@'
forward:9: unknown RR type 'server1'
forward:10: unknown RR type 'server2'
zone shancked.com/IN: loading from master file forward failed: unknown class/type
zone shancked.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/shancked.com/IN: unknown class/type
zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
                                                           [FAILED]
```

and here is my /etc/named.rfc1912.zones file contents:

```
zone "localhost.localdomain" IN {
        type master;
        file "named.localhost";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "localhost" IN {
        type master;
        file "named.localhost";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "named.loopback";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "named.loopback";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "0.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "named.empty";
        allow-update { none; };
};
```

here is the forward file:

```
$TTL 1D
$ORIGIN example.tv.
@       IN SOA  server1.example.tv. root.server.example.tv. (
                                2018020211              ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum
;
;
        @        IN NS server1.example.tv.
        server1 IN  A  10.0.2.17
        server2 IN  A  10.0.2.16
```

here is the key file:

```
server1.shancked.com. {
algorithm hmac-md5;
secret sml8ZD7dKHzINlkIjZRD0w==;

};
```

after updating the key file i get the following error:

```
zone example.tv IN {
type master;
file "forward";
allow-update { key server1.example.tv; };
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
include "/etc/named/server.key";
```

server.key file:

```
key server1.example.tv {
algorithm hmac-md5;
secret "EeLHcvOPr4cCaEySX1jBbw==";

};
```

error message:

```
[shan@server1 named]$ sudo service named restart
Stopping named:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting named:
Error in named configuration:
forward:11: unknown RR type '@'
forward:12: unknown RR type 'server1'
forward:13: unknown RR type 'server2'
zone example.tv/IN: loading from master file forward failed: unknown class/type
zone example.tv/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/example.tv/IN: unknown class/type
zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Comment: try inspecting or regenerating the secrets in the `*.key` files, which is usually base64 encoded but apparently not in your case. this is usually done with `rndc-confgen` for `named.root.key`.

Comment: I don't think this is your whole named.conf file, the error is on line 163 and what you show is only 51 lines long.

Comment: @wurtel thats the confusing part to me too why is it showing more than the usual lines

Comment: It might be counting the lines from the included file as well. Move the `include "/etc/named.root.key";` line to above the previous include statement, and see if that "fixes" the line number.

Comment: @wurtel i still face the same problem

Comment: @thrig any ideas

Comment: same questions as before. we can't tell what is wrong if we can't see the secrets (which should not be shared) which leaves looking at them yourself to see what is wrong, and either fixing or regenerating the secrets as necessary

Comment: can i know the path to the secrets?? @thrig

Comment: I don't know if you can. Hint: look for `file` or `include` configuration statements.

Comment: @jackal4me same line number in the error message?

Comment: Why not generate another secret and paste it here in the same format you've used your real key with?

Comment: @TorinCarey i think that this is a problem with syntax

Comment: @jackal4me which is why you should post it in the same style that you've used for your real key

Comment: @TorinCarey did that and i get the same problem once again

Comment: @jackal4me I meant for you to post your configuration with the newly generated key in place of the real key. The error `bad secret 'bad base64 encoding'` is almost certainly incorrect use of the key in configuration

Comment: @TorinCarey sorry for the misunderstanding i have included the server key above

Comment: @TorinCarey i followed as you said and most of the error message went away but now i get a new error like this `Error in named configuration:
/etc/named/server.key:1: unknown option 'server1.example.tv.'
                                                           [FAILED]
`

Answer (score 0):

Your key declaration is incorrect.

```
server1.shancked.com. {
    algorithm hmac-md5;
    secret [base64_secret];
};
```

Should be

```
key "key_name" {
    algorithm hmac-md5;
    secret "[base64_secret]";
};
```

where `key_name` should be referred to appropriately in named.conf.

Comment: now it says like this `Error in named configuration:
/etc/named/server.key:1: unknown option 'server1.example.tv.'
                                                           [FAILED]
`

Comment: I assume you've tried to start a key declaration with `server1.example.tv. { ...` when it should be of the form `key "key_name" { ...`. Make sure you understand what TSIG keys are and what they're used for. It almost looks like you're trying to do DNSSEC...

Comment: again the same problem bro it is spewing out the first error message again

Comment: the keys name is server1.example.tv only

Comment: If your key name is server1.example.tv then you should start the key declaration with `key "server1.example.tv" {`

Comment: i did exactly as you instructed me ill update for you to see it.@torincarey

Comment: On the last three lines of your zone file, get rid of the spaces before the record names.